gui login problen after upgrade
Upgrade worked BUT gui login says session exists for user, and force close doesn't do anything.
Ctrl-alt-f5 allows login and seems to show upgrade worked.
No idea what to do now

Google "Recovery console" and try to get to it; there try to fsck, enable networking and then drop to root (hit Enter one extra time!), read at least the last lines of dmesg | less or even further earlier text to try find what the culprit might be. dmesg is one of the files in /var/log/ - use less filename to read other files there, might reveal more zcat filename | less will display contents of those that have a name ending in .gz .  Edit and add text above if you find something suspect.
